"Error: Body exceeded 1 MB limit" using Next.js server
When I'm sending an array with over 1MB file size to a Next.js server then I'm getting Body exceeded 1 MB limit:

I have tried to resolve this by adding a file-size configuration in next.config.js but that did not work once the file-size configuration was added. The same with the server file which still did not resolve the problem.
"use server"

import { connectToDatabase } from "@/mongodb/connectToMongo";

export default async({document={}})=>{
    const db = await connectToDatabase();
    const collection = db.collection("excels");
    const response=await collection.insertOne(document)
    const { insertedId } = response;
    return insertedId
}

export const config={
    api:{
        bodyParser:{
            sizeLimit:"10mb"
        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: Body exceeded 1mb limit error in Next.js API route. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

next.config.js
   /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: false,
      experimental: {
        serverActions: {
          //  change file size limit
          bodySizeLimit: "1000MB", 
        },
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["@react-pdf/renderer"],
      },
      //  to access images links globally
      images: {
        remotePatterns: [
          {
            protocol: "https",
            hostname: "**",
            port: "",
            pathname: "/**/**",
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    
    export default nextConfig;

